# Conditional Formatting for an Excel file

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm having some issues with some conditional formatting in Excel. I have attached a screenshot of my page for reference. What I want to to happen is this:

For each test subject, or for each listed person, if the Total Daily Points cell has a value greater than or equal to 8, *or* the Weekly Total Points has a cell has a total of greater than or equal to 12, the Error Code section should turn red. No matter what combination or variation on these rules that I try, it seems to have the unintended result of turning ***all*** of the error code section red. The rules that I have are shown in the screenshot link below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2M0q.jpg)
[image: Excel Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you clear all Conditional Formatting from the sheet then select ColumnsC:Q and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=OR($R1>=8,$T1>=12)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select red Fill, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.